# JS: how to find a specific string, then extract an integer?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, integer, userscripts

I'm trying to write a userscript for a game I'm playing. It uses this piece of HTML code:

```
    <td valign="center">
      <b>ten-leaf clover</b>
       (4 left in stock for today)
    </td>
```

This is a picture of what we're talking about:

[image]

The script should search for a string containing the words "left in stock for today", then look for an integer within this string. (The '4' is not constant, it changes every day.) Lastly, I would like to store this integer as a variable, so I can replace the '1' in the input field. Like this:

```
    var clover = EnterCodeHere
    $("input.text[name='quantity']").val(clover);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used a regex like so:

```
var textToSearch = $("td").innerHtml(); //You'll need a better selector than this. better to use a class or id
var clover = parseInt(textToSearch.match(/\d+\s*left in stock for today/)[0].match(/\d+/)[0]);
$("input.text[name='quantity']").val(clover);
```

You may want to check the array isn't empty before just taking the first value but if your confident it'll be there should be grand.

Comment: "You may want to check the array isn't empty before just taking the first value but if your confident it'll be there should be grand."

Sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I meant that the match function will return an array and if '\d\s*left in stock for today' is in the textToSearch it will be in  the array, if it's not it won't be. Apologies for using the word 'grand' in that context, I'm Irish and we generally use that word to mean ok or fine.

Comment: btw It doesn't work. Does this actually store only the integer as 'clover'? I'm not familiar with regexs, but I'll look it up.

Comment: Sorry, just added the code to the answer to turn it into an integer now :)

Comment: Still doesn't work. I just googled regex and figured this might work as well, but it doesn't.
        var clover = /\d/.exec($("td").innerHTML());
        $("input.text[name='quantity']").val(clover);

Comment: Do you perhaps know a way to create an array of all the integers in the page and select the 2nd one? Because the integer I'm looking for is always the 2nd on that page. Might be a more simple approach.

Comment: Sure all you have to do is `var clover = parseInt($("body").text().match(/\d+/g)[1]);`, that will get the second number on the page.

Comment: Thanks! Should I mark the question as answered? I mean, my problem is solved, but the initial question is still unanswered.

Comment: Please I think the point is to solve your problem and you'll probably agree, I've done that.